# Memory leak, realloc() function

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Here I want to extract words from `'text'` string. Dr. Memory says to me I have memory leak at line `words = (char**) realloc(words, (amount + 1) * sizeof(char*));` What is the problem?

```
p = strtok(text, " ");
while(p != NULL) {
    words = (char**) realloc(words, (amount + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    words[amount] = strdup(p);
    amount ++;
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
for(i = 0; i < amount; i ++) {
       free(words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whn you use `strdup` it will allocate a new string. So before you release the array, you need to free each string you allocated with `strdup`.

You are not freeing the whole array though. The part you are allocating with `realloc`.

So what is missing is a simple:

```
free(words);
```

Comment: Actually it seems to be exactly what he does, he just forgets to free the actual array.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, yeah, right, I just notioced it as well. :)

Comment: i do it in my cycle below

Comment: @user3021370 You never `free(words);`